# Add a header to existing CSV file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I have a CSV file with five columns and hundreds of rows. I would like to add a header to each column. such as

| number | Test | data1 | data2 | DataNs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zero | test0 | random | random | random |
| firster | test1 | random | random | random |
| First | test2 | random | random | random |
| Second | test3 | random | random | random |

I have tried the following code, which does add the headers successfully, however, it is also combining all columns into one. which is not what I want

```
import-csv $NoHeadersExport -Header 'number', 'Test', 'data1', 'data2', 'DataNs' | export-csv $exportPath  -NoTypeInformation
```

this code is leading to following table

| number | Test | data1 | data2 | DataNs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zerotest0randomrandomrandom |  |  |  |  |
| firstertest1randomrandomrandom |  |  |  |  |
| Firsttest2randomrandomrandom |  |  |  |  |
| Secondtest3randomrandomrandom |  |  |  |  |

Comment: what is the raw data of the csv? what is the separator/delimiter?

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz it's comma

Comment: that's very strange. 1. where do the semicolon come from? 2. why are there none in line two?

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz Sorry, those semicolons were a output from another trial-error code. I fixed the table now.

Answer (score 2):

using plain text you could do it like so:

1. get the csv (wihtout the header) and store it in a variable

   ```
   $csvContent = Get-Content C:\path\to\file.csv -Raw
   ```
2. create the header line as string

   ```
   $csvHeader = '"number","Test","data1","data2","DataNs"'
   ```
3. combine these two variables

   ```
   $csvContentWithHeader = $csvHeader,$csvContent -join "`n"
   ```
4. save the CSV with header as file

   ```
   Out-File -FilePath C:\path\to\fileWithHeader.csv -InputObject $csvContentWithHeader
   ```

Comment: This is doing the opposite now, columns are all there but its adding headers to only first column with following syntax  `number,"Test","data1",data2","DataNs"`

Comment: Then please provide raw data

Answer (score 0):

I have instead created another CSV file and then merged both with Add-Content command which somehow worked.

```
#file that has all the columns but no header
$withoutheaders = "C:\export.csv"
#blank csv
$headersonly = "C:\headers.csv"
Set-Content $headersonly -Value "number,Test,data1,data2,DataNs"
$addheaders = Get-Content -Path $withoutheaders
Add-Content -Path $headersonly -Value $addheaders
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work if you remove the single quotes from the header names.

```
    import-csv $NoHeadersExport -Header number,Test,data1,data2,DataNs | export-csv $exportPath  -NoTypeInformation
```